# Dead electrical outlets in garage

Tags: gfci

1. Garage and (1) exterior outlet on porch & (1) exterior GFCI outlet in back of house are all on the same circuit breaker.
2. All circuit breakers in the panel are on.
3. All GFCI outlets in Kitchen have power.
4. The GFCI outlet in the back of the house, has power (working) but I replaced it with new one just to make sure it is ok. (Still working)
5. No downstream feed from GFCI to anything else (only white brown & copper in) so I assume the porch outlet & garage outlets that has no power must be upstream. 
   Do not know where else to look. Please help.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A diagram of the wiring would be really helpful; if you can't edit in the picture, edit in a URL and someone will be by to change it to the actual picture.

Comment: Have you used a meter to check the output terminals on the GFCI?

Answer (score 1):

Check the load and line connections on gfci. If not wired correctly you may still get power at the gfci but power will not be carried on to the other outlet/switches. There should be 2 cables in the box. The one providing power is your "line" the other is "load".